# Not able to scan PDF 417 barcode using camera in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am trying to generate and scan a PDF 417 barcode using camera. I able to do this on iOS 7 pretty smoothly but camera, on iOS 6, is not able to detect PDF 417. Anybody worked on this before and have some clue, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Pdf417 scanning is only supported on iOS 7 and later.

Look at the documentation of  [AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/)